# Create single UIImage from high resolution camera images for printing

Tags: ios, objective-c, printing, uiimage, resolution

I'm trying to create a single UIImage from multiple UIImages and a label.  I know how to create this in the view, and it looks fine.  The problem is that I want this single image printed by a professional printing company.  The minimum resolution the printing company accepts is 1838x1238.  The view resolution is obviously much smaller than this.  I want to create a high resolution UIImage from several camera images and include a label, but the high resolution copy won't be displayed (b/c I figure it will crash the app).  I can't do a screen shot or use UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() because of the resolution issue.  I am completely stumped, and help would be appreciated!

Comment: Huh. Why is the the view resolution "obviously smaller than this"? You can set a view to any size.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to set the view size to 1838x1838, you could always draw the picture into a Core Graphics image context, like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(1838.0, 1838.0), NO, 1); //Scale is 1 so the resolution isn't necessarily doubled for retina devices - change to zero if you want this
[image drawInRect:firstImageRect];
//.....
[labelText drawInRect:labelTextRect]; //labelText is an NSString or NSAttributedString
finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Hope this helps!